# Filtering out HTML tags not working w preg_replace

Tags: filter, hook

I have some posts that (in the actual post text on the backend) has some errant `<strong> </strong>` entries.  I'm trying to filter these out before being rendered as HTML.  (Note that I do have proper tags also, e.g. `<strong>This Is a Title</strong>` that I need to keep).

I have created a filter, but can't seem to get the strip to work:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'filter_test');
function filter_test($content){
  global $post;
  $post_slug = $post->post_name;
  if (get_post_type() == "post" && $post_slug != "allposts") {
    $content = preg_replace("/<strong>\s+<\/strong>/",'',$content); // THIS LINE
    $content = preg_replace("/&nbsp;|^\s*$/",'',$content);
    return $content;
  }
  return $content;
}
```

It still leaves in the "empty" `<strong>` tags.  As far as I can tell, I have the correct regex pattern, `<strong>\s+<\/strong>` (and added `/` around that, as that seems to be the PHP way).

How can I **remove/filter out** empty tags (`<strong> </strong>`) but **keep** "filled" ones (`<strong>Words here</strong>`)?

Edit: Snapshot of some of the HTML code when the page is rendered:

```
<p>USA is a country</p>
<p><strong> </strong></p>
<p><strong>then there are some words here.</strong></p>
<p><strong> </strong></p>
```

I'm trying to remove the second and fourth line in that.  I see now technically I want to remove empty `<p></p>` but the solution I expect would work for any HTML tag.

Comment: Have you tried different preg_replace for the opening and closing tags?

Comment: @LiamStewart - Do you mean on separate lines? Wouldn't doing that also remove the ones I want to keep, `<strong>words here</strong>` instead of just empty ones, `<strong> </strong>`?

Comment: Ohhh I understand the ask. Give me a few and I'll make something.

Comment: Using regular expressions to parse HTML isn't a good idea, consider an XML parser, but tbh, this isn't a WP question, it's a general PHP string manipulation question, perhaps stack overflow would be better?

Comment: @TomJNowell - Agreed (I admit I struggle knowing what's specific issue with WP, and programming in general). Thanks for the migration.  And yeah, I know using [regex to parse HTML is not good](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4650297), but was hoping [this may be an "exception" of sorts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1733489/4650297)?

Comment: A good metric is if WP knowledge is needed to answer the question. In this case, the content could be from any CMS, it's the general case of how to remove empty `strong` tags in a HTML string using PHP that you're wanting

Comment: @TomJNowell Thanks for your comments. I'm still new to WP too, so I don't know what WP knowledge is needed, for what I need to know :P  (...mainly, wasn't sure if my filter use was correct [WP] or if it's the regex/preg_replace [PHP] issue).

Comment: Your filter use is fine, just be mindful that all post content on the page will have the filter applied not just the main content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `str_replace`

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'filter_test');
function filter_test($content){
    global $post;
    $post_slug = $post->post_name;
    if (get_post_type() === 'post' && $post_slug != 'allposts') {
        $content = str_replace(array(<strong></strong>","<strong> </strong>"),'',$content); // THIS LINE
        $content = preg_replace("/&nbsp;|^\s*$/",'',$content);
        return $content;
    }
    return $content;
}
```

Will remove the following in the content:

```
<strong></strong>
<strong> </strong>
```

Comment: Hm, that isn't doing it for some reason.  I edited my OP to show the HTML, turns out I really need `<p> </p>` removed but the issue is the same. I tried replacing your strings with `<p><strong> </strong></p>` and it didn't filter anything. What am I missing perhaps?

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't remove/filter them :/  To be clear - in the post itself it's just `<strong>` tags. When rendered by WP when you visit the page, it adds the `p` tags around each line.

Comment: Right -  try replacing the empty string with `hello` or something. Updated my answer again.

Comment: Interesting! If I just do `...str_replace("<strong>","FUNKYTOWN", $content)`, it successfully replaces all `<strong>` tags with `FUNKYTOWN`.  But (!) when I change that to `...str_replace("<p></strong> </strong></p>", "FUNKYTOWN", $content)`, nothing seems to get replaced.  I will test and see if *not* using `p` tags helps.  Edit: I just tried `...str_replace("<strong> </strong", "FUNKYTOWN", $content)` and nothing was filtered/removed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181979/discussion-between-brucewayne-and-liam-stewart).

Comment: So, after an hour or three of trying at this, I am coming to the conclusion that I **cannot** remove `<p><strong> </strong></p>` via a filter with either Regex or Str_replace.  I can remove `<p> </p>` but when I add in the `strong` tags, nothing gets filtered out.  Should I just abandon this idea?

Comment: By all accounts [the RegEx does match what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckmSp.jpg)...it's just not filtering out?

Comment: Try without `p` tags. Also try replacing with `' '` instead of `''`

Comment: I swear I tried that before, but it seems to be working now. I used `$content = preg_replace("/<strong>\s*<\/strong>/ m", ' ', $content);`. ...except now it is replacing my `' '` with `<br/>`??

Comment: For the record - this is what seemed to work in the end: `$content = preg_replace(array("/&nbsp;|^\s*$/","/<strong>\s*<\/strong>/ m", "/<br\/>/", "/<p>\s*<\/p>/"), ' ', $content);`